# Turf difference function and coincident polygon boundaries

Tags: turf

[image: Blue Polgyon on top of Dark Red Polygon]

[image]

I've been wrestling with this issue for a few days.

The tool I'm creating takes one polygon and essentially minuses/subtracts another from it. A perfect use of the difference command in Turf.

The problems seem to arise when the polygons have the same boundaries for part of their areas. By boundaries I mean, imagine two polygons on top of each other, these are not polygons that border each other. One is on top and they have the same outline for part of their extents.

In the image, note the dark red outline of the polygon, a portion of which is being subtracted from the blue outline polygon (the blue polygon is on top, so along part of the coast the two polygons have the same outline).

Two polygons that intersect, but have no common boundaries are no problem, and I've done my best to ensure this is the case as much as possible. However unfortunately this isn't always possible.

What the difference command returns is the correct polygon minus the polygon subtracted, just what I wanted.

However it tends to include other small features that lie outside this polygon but along what was the common (think vertical here) boundary.

In the image showing after the function has run, note the small blue line (it's really a small polygon) along the coast directly north of the correctly processed polygon. It shouldn't matter, but as an FYI, the blue polygon is created by an earlier process, using a user created polygon that uses the intersect turf function, the intersect restricts the polygon creation to within the country boundaries.

It's as if the algorithm cannot cookie cut if it's too close to the edge of the dough (I am interested in, of course, the dough here outside the cookie cutter).

Be interested to hear if anyone else has had this issue and would have a workaround or post processing idea.

Comment: welcome to GIS SE! I think a diagram would help. [This chart](https://www.flickr.com/photos/stevefaeembra/34500665382) shows the possible overlap/intersection possibilities, which one best represents your scenario? Feel free to clip out that part of the diagram and add it to your question.

Comment: An example (picture and code) where you have problems would be helpful in helping you.

Comment: Note that GIS SE uses a Focused question/Best answer model, so questions which appear to be soliciting opinions run along the ragged edge of getting closed as *opinion-based*, while questions which are unfocused risk being closed as *too broad*.

Comment: What are the dimension of your "error" GeoJSON? Is it line string or polygon? How does it's coordinates match with coordinates of polygons that were used for difference?

Comment: If the small "line" is actually a small polygon, as you say, then this is just the correct output of the difference algorithm. What you have is a second criteria (not an erroneous output), perhaps based on size?

Comment: What is your question?  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. Really appreciate it. I now cannot reproduce this error so I believe it was corrupt data. I'm continuing to have issues with the difference command and I suspect it's related to creating data in leaflet, interacting with existing data via crunching it through Turf. Somewhere along the way there is a precision issue or data corruption. If anyone has a leaflet/turf link/paper to a example code repository, that would be great. Thanks again.@TomazicM